# Copying Media Player Object

Tags: android

If I create a copy of a MediaPlayer object, which object will a callback function be called on.  For example:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer mp_copy = mp;

mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(...);
mp_copy.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(...);
```

When the buffer is updated, which object will receive the callback (or will both of them)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
MediaPlayer mp_copy = mp;
```

you are *not* making a copy of a MediaPlayer object. You are making a new reference to the same object. The second call to `setOnBufferingUpdateListener` will undo the effect of the first call.